# Вызов функции/объекта

Tags: javascript, функции

Такой вопрос. 
Если есть необходимость вызвать функцию, то можно использовать `window[myfunction]`.
А если нужно вызвать метод объекта, имея имя объекта в строковой переменной? Т.е. `myobject.myfunction(param)`.
Есть ли возможность правильно вызвать метод объекта?

p.s. имея значение в переменной, можно ли проверить - существует ли такой объект или функция?

Comment: что?

    var obj = {
        x: 10,
        func: function(x) {
            return this.x*x;
        }
    };
    var func = obj.func;

    obj.func(10); // 100
    obj['func'](10); // 100
    func.apply(obj, [10]); // 100

Comment: Сори. Имеется ввиду вызов по строчке. Т.е. в вашем примере 'obj'

Comment: Поправил вопрос

Comment: а ведь вопрос явно про `eval`...я отказываюсь на него отвечать

Comment: Использовать eval в данном случае не безопасно.

Comment: @Spectre - где здесь eval? O_o

Comment: если объект НЕ глобальный и не другие объекты не содержат его ссылок, имея только его имя без `eval` его не вызвать. или я не прав?

Comment: Как-бы на практике, если есть необходимость в функционале такого рода - все "вызываемые" объекты хранятся в хэше. В другом случае - да, но, как понял я, автора интересовало не это.

Comment: Все же глобальные интересуют.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отдохните уважаемый...

```
var obj = {
   someCoolMethod : function(){ console.log('works') }
}
var method = 'someCoolMethod';
obj[ method ]( /* ... */ ); // -> works

// проверка на существование
if( obj[ method ] ) {
    // ...
}

// если имя объекта задано строчкой
// и находиться оно в глобальной области видимости, то вызвать можно так
var objName = 'obj', method = 'someCoolMethod';
window[ objName ][ method ]();

// но, естественно, для безопасного вызова метода нужно написать условие вида
if( window[ objName ] && window[ objName ][ method ] ) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: А если  и имя объекта задано строчкой? возможно?

Comment: Хм, все же я был близок. Спасибо, век живи, век учись. 
p.s. сори за довольно простой вопрос.